# Integral of a covariance function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, probability-theory, covariance

Let a covariance function be $COV(y(X),y(X'))=R(X,X')$ and $\mathbf{E}_{y}^{Q}=\int\limits_{X_Q} y(X)\ dX_Q$, in which $X_Q$ is a subset of $X$. Why does $COV(\mathbf{E}_{y}^{Q},y(X'))=\int\limits_{X_Q}R(X,X')dX_Q$ hold? Does anyone give me a hand to explain that equation? Ths.

Comment: If I understand your notations correctly, $E_y^Q$ is a constant. Covariance of any random variable with a constant is zero. Isn't that true?

Comment: $\mathbf{E}^{Q}_{y}$ denotes the expectation of $Y(X)$ with respect to a subset of inputs $X_Q$. Assume $y(X)=f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, so ${E}^{1}_{y}=\int\limits_{X_1} f(x_1,x_2,x_3)dx_1$.